# Salesforce developer console - APEX runner

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to run code in the developer console. From the "execute anonymous window". How do i access the case written in the console from the child window.
it shows the attached error when trying to execute
[image: anonymous execute window]

[image: error]

---

I am still getting the same error. screenshot below. Please let me know if the screenshots are visible otherwise i will upload somewhere else.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Test" is a name of a built-in apex class used when writing unit tests. It's bad idea to name your own classes like the standard ones, it can lead to "fun" scenarios like "integer account = 5; sobject a = new account();"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_test.htm

Make new class with similar body, delete that one and try your code again.
And since your method is static, you can do MyClass.myTest(), you don't need "new"

Comment: It is still throwing the same error

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8sW3Mla

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/all3BdN

Comment: issue displayed in screenshot on previous links

Comment: Use the file uploader in the editor, not 3rd parties. I'm using adblock and imgur is very annoying about that. Did you actually save that MyHelloWorld class? No errors?